# How do I set initial form values of CreateView view using POST only (and not GET)?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Users click a button that takes them to a new form via a POST request, which contains a pk. This is used to pre-populate the new form with some extra data. No data has been saved to database at this point. I don't want to pass this pk along the URL so can't call view using GET.

I've tried overriding the `get_initial()` method in CreateView but this only seems to be called after a GET request.

I've also tried `def post()` which gives me easy access to the fields but means I have to write more code to handle form validation etc (which is handled automagically by the vanilla CreateView).

So, what's the best way to handle rendering and saving of a form when both requests are made via POST?

Comment: This is a strange requirement. Why can't you display the form using GET? That's the normal pattern; POST is for making changes, not displaying data.

Comment: The form is to book an appointment for a pet owner and his/her pets. I want to pre-populate the form with the owner and pet names. I can't simply pass PK of owner because not all of their pets will be in the appointment, and I can't just pass pet pk because there might be more than one.

Comment: ..using POST I can pass a list of pet PKs. Not sure how I'd do that cleanly via GET.

Comment: You can have multiple pets in the GET parameters, e.g. `?pet=1&pet=2`. Use `request.GET.getlist('pet')` to retrieve them.

Comment: Yeah, just seems a bit 1998, that's all :)

Comment: You could just pass the params you submitted with the first request to the context and render them as hidden inputs on the second page into the form.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do:

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    # Replace 'list_of_pets' with stuff that you'll definitely have in the first request
    if 'list_of_pets' in request.POST:
        # Provide initial data for form in get()
        return self.get(request, **kwargs)
    else:
        # Provides automatic form validation
        return super().post(request, **kwargs)
```

In the `get()` method you can set the initial data and whatnot. You could also use a completely separate method, but overriding `get()` gives you the benefit that if someone wanders to the URL without a POST request, they don't get a nasty 405 right away (of course there are other ways to get avoid that it, just sayin').